# Error: Illegal arguments for construction of _exports_Spi

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-core

I've tried installing MRAA both via apt and building it from its github source.  I can run mraa-gpio and mraa-i2c on the commandline, and I can turn LEDs on and off with the GPIO javascript example.  But, when I try to run the SPI javascript example, I get an error at the moment of instantiation:

```
(classic)thosmos@localhost:~/hello-node$ sudo nodejs
> var m = require('mraa');
undefined
> x = new m.Spi(0)
Error: Illegal arguments for construction of _exports_Spi
  at Error (native)
  at repl:1:5
  at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:252:27)
  at bound (domain.js:287:14)
  at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:300:12)
  at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:417:12)
  at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
  at REPLServer.emit (events.js:169:7)
  at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:210:10)
  at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:549:8)
>
```

Is there a step I'm missing for getting this working?

Comment: What hardware is this on?

Comment: This is on an Intel Joule

Comment: And running Ubuntu Core 16.04

Comment: The Joule is a bit different. I've logged a bug for this issue to be investigated and will report back once I have an answer.

Comment: Thanks for following up on this.  Where was this bug report logged (with Ubuntu, Intel, or somewhere else)?

Comment: I'm afraid it's a private bug. The outcome, though, is that Intel has a tool to enable SPI, but is not yet ready to release it without an NDA. You might consider talking to them.

Comment: @Kyle I see the same error on BeagleBone. Did you find any fix for this?